# How to change color of multiple rows onClick angular materialUI

Tags: angular, material-ui

I can change color of a cell when i click on showProfile(). But if I click next row the previous color disappears.
How can I keep the color persistent for each time I click any row?

I have this in my HTML:

```
   <ng-container *ngIf="col === 'name'">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{ col | titlecase }} </mat-header-cell>
       <mat-cell *matCellDef=" let row" 
               [ngClass]="{'data-selected': selectedRow ===row.id}" >
      <a mat-button color="primary" (click)="showProfile(row['id'], row)"
        target="_blank">{{ row[col] }}</a>
      </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>
```

And my CSS :

```
    .data-selected {
         background-color:rgb(34, 110, 34);
       }
```

And the TS:

```
    selectedRow = -1;


showProfile(id, row) {
this.selectedRow = id;
this.dialog.open(ViewProfileAdminComponent, {
  width: '1800px',
  data: {
    userId: id,
    isAdmin: true,
  },
});
```

}
[image: This produces the following result:]
Thanks in advance...

Comment: you only has an unique variable that get's the value of the row clicked, so you only can select one row. If you want to select severals rows you need an array or rows selected -or the object of your array has a property selected-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Example Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xgt3qm?file=src/app/app.component.ts) Because u made selectedrow only one element. You need to return it to array. Each click you should insert if not and delete if exists to array and in condition u should check if it inside it.

use

```
[ngClass]="{'data-selected': selectedRow.indexOf(row.id) !== -1}"
```

and in your component change selectedRow to array

```
 selectedRow=[];
```

then in your function

put below code

```
showProfile(id, row) {
     this.selectedRow.find(x=>x==id) ? this.selectedRow=this.selectedRow.filter(x=>x!=id) : this.selectedRow.push(id);
```